# [Get-Content], ItemNotFoundException : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand in VSTS PowerShell task

Tags: powershell, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-rm-template

Am working on ARM Templates Deployment using powershell Command line

`$manifestDetails = Get-Content ./manifest.json | ConvertFrom-Json`

which is going to be find and run the .json file .It is running fine in my **local PC**. But when am running the same line through **VSTS PowerShell task**, then am receiving following issue:

> At C:\XX_work\r7\a\CIBuild\drop\XX\XX\Deployment\Manif
>   estAzureDeployment.ps1:191 char:21
>   +     $manifestDetails = Get-Content ./manifest.json | ConvertFrom-Json
>   +                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\XX...a\manifest.json:String) [Get-Content], ItemNotFoundEx
>   ception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand

So, please give me suitable suggestions for this issue

Comment: `./manifest.json` is _relative_ to the context in which your command is running. Run a `Get-Location` command beforehand to spot the difference¬

Comment: Always use full paths in scripts unless you know with certainty what the relative path is going to be.

Comment: Do you solve this issue?

Comment: Yes @starianchen-MSFT. I solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using absolute path through [built-in release variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/release/variables?view=vsts&tabs=batch#default-variables) instead.

For example, `System.DefaultWorkingDirectory` (`$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)`): The directory to which artifacts are downloaded during deployment of a release. The directory is cleared before every deployment if it requires artifacts to be downloaded to the agent. Same as `Agent.ReleaseDirectory` and `System.ArtifactsDirectory`.